# Uncaught Error: Invalid configuration of route 'feed'. One of the following must be provided: component, redirectTo, children or loadChildren

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-routing

I am getting this error only when building for production. No error when building for stage or dev. Does anyone know what I did wrong with my app-routing module? Is there a race condition happening here? How would I restructure this to avoid the error? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { VoteHistoryComponent } from './vote-history/vote-history.component';
import { PollHistoryComponent } from './poll-history/poll-history.component';
import { PollShowComponent } from './poll-show/poll-show.component';
import sportTypes from '../assets/types/sport-types.json'

const feedRoutes = sportTypes.types.map(type => {
  return { path: type.name, component: DashboardComponent }
});

const voteHistoryRoutes = sportTypes.types.map(type => {
  return { path: type.name, component: VoteHistoryComponent }
});

const pollHistoryRoutes = sportTypes.types.map(type => {
  return { path: type.name, component: PollHistoryComponent }
});

const pollShowRoutes = sportTypes.types.map(type => {
  return {
    path: type.name,
    children: [{
      path: ':id', component: PollShowComponent
    }]
  }
});

const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/feed/football', pathMatch: 'full'},
  { path: 'feed',
    children: feedRoutes
  },
  { path: 'history',
    children: voteHistoryRoutes
  },
  { path: 'polls',
    children: pollHistoryRoutes
  },
  { path: 'poll',
    children: pollShowRoutes
  }
];

@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

Comment: Did you try to switch places with history route and put it first and see if the same error appears for it as well?

Comment: Is the difference between dev and prod that you are using aot for prod?

Comment: I'm using the default ng build --configuration=production command and did not pass the aot flag

Comment: If I switch places with history route I get the same error for route 'history'